# Python word_tokenize

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I'm quite new in python. I'm trying to find Frequency Distributions of my text. Here is the code,

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
import os
os.getcwd()
text_file=open(r"ecelebi\1.txt","r")
p = text_file.read()
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(p)
fdist= FreqDist(words)
print(fdist)
```

The problem is that program is not giving any error or solution. It is just returning this

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
showing info http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/
```

I think the problem is with word_tokenize(). 
I would appreciate, if you can help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Your issue is that you're trying to run `nltk.download()` in a script and the GUI is appearing hidden somewhere behind your pages.

Generally, `nltk.download()` is usually ran in the Python interpreter, it allows you to download various datasets and corpuses (corpii? :P) for use with nltk. You usually only have to do this once, only using it again if you want to update your corpuses. **You don't have to run it every single time you run a script.**

Assuming you've ran `nltk.download()` in the Python interpreter then you will either get some form of GUI, or if you're not able to have access to GUIs (for example if you're SSHd in without X-forwarding) then it'll be a command line interface. You can use this to download the data. I'd recommend just downloading it all, unless you're stretched for space.

Once you've ran `nltk.download()` and downloaded everything you think you'll need, then the code below should work.

```
import nltk
import os

os.getcwd()
text_file=open(r"ecelebi\1.txt","r")

p = text_file.read()
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(p)

fdist= nltk.FreqDist(words)
print(fdist)
```

*Note that the command is `nltk.FreqDist`, not `FreqDist`, because the function is in the `nltk` namespace.*